# Handling multiple gestures simultaneously

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have two subviews view1 and view2. I have added LongPress and Pan gesture to my parentview.
When I longPress on view1, I will present a draggableview with popup animation just below the fingure and will continue dragging dragView to view2.
In this process panGesture selector is not called but Longpress gesture selector is called.
After i remove the fingure from dragview and then start dragging again then the panGesture selector is called.

What I need is, once the dragview is created, disable(not permanently but until pan gesture state ended is called) the longpress gesture and the pan gesture selector should be called

Answer (score 4):

You have a delegate method called:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Take a look at it, you need to return YES.